# Composite Key mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Below is the 3 table details that i need to use.It has some other columns other than the listed below. I need to join the Line items table and Material Details table to fetch the material details into line items table. And i need to use the Hibernate HBM.xml mapping.
Not sure how to fetch details.

```
Promo Header            Line Items            MaterialDetails
1. Promo Code(Pk)       1.LineItem Id(Pk)     1.MaterialCode(PK)
2. Sales Org(FK)        2.Promo Code(FK)     2.Sales Org(PK)
                        3.MaterialCode
```

Please help me out in the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  @EmbeddedId for that purpose  [**ANNOTATION MAPPING**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819)

```
<composite-id>
<key-property name="name1" column="col1"  />
<key-property name="name2" column="col2" />
</composite-id>
```

[**XML MAPPING**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid)

Comment: I Couldn't understand map with embeddedId. I am using xml mapping instead of annotation. Could you please help me out.

Comment: @Jothi did you understand that